# Show error page when no internet (html)

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a website and wanted to know how I can show a custom error page when there is no internet connection. For example,

[image: screenshot]

Comment: checkout offline.js here https://github.com/hubspot/offline

Comment: You can generally do this, when you are making a AJAX call or some request to server and your client can check for offline response back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`offline` and `online` events in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events).

Here's a simple snippet that alerts the user on these events, but you can extend the idea to present a better UI.

```js
window.addEventListener("online", function() {
  alert("You are online now!");
});

window.addEventListener("offline", function() {
  alert("Oops! You are offline now!");
});
```

Also, note that you can check whether the page is online or not using `navigator.onLine`

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  console.log("You are online");
} else {
  console.log("You are offline");
}
```

Note: You can test these in Chrome through Network tab, where there is an option to take the tab offline temporarily.

Comment: Nice one! Worked like a charm!

Comment: The above solution will not works in all cases like when any  issue occurred from network provider. To solve all scenarios you can you service worker or see the below article
https://link.medium.com/xu2cVcvV6xb

Comment: to be honest i was expecting the kind of offline display as **Crazy games**  but this works